# Solve $ab + cd = -1; ac + bd = -1; ad + bc = -1$ over the integers

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, integers

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Solve the system of equations
>   \begin{align}
> \begin{cases}
> ab + cd = -1 \\
> ac + bd = -1 \\
> ad + bc = -1
> \end{cases}
> \end{align}
>   for the integers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

I have found that the first equation gives $d = \dfrac{-1-cd}{a}$, which gives $a\neq0$. Other than that, I don't know where to start.

Tips, help or solution is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't "give $a\neq 0.$" The equality is only true ir $a\neq 0.$ If $a=0,$ then it requires that $cd=-1,bd=-1,$ and $bc=-1.$ This shows that $a\neq 0,$ because when $b,c,d\in\{-1,+1\}$ then two of $a,b,c$ are equal and then their product is not $-1.$ So $a\neq 0.$ This is true for all $a,b,c,d.$

Comment: The first equation (alone) does not tell you that $a \ne 0$.  Take $a=0; b=2; c=1; d=-1$ then $ab + cd = -1$ is true.  You can't say $b = \frac {-1-cd}a$ and so $a \ne 0$.  You have to say:  Either $a \ne 0$ and $b = \frac {-1-cd}a$ or $a = 0$ and $cd = -1$.  You can't assume that just because you *have* $a$ you can divide by $a$.  You have to consider *both* cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add equation 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3 you get

$(a+d)(b+c)=-2$

$(a+c)(b+d)=-2$

$(a+b)(c+d)=-2$

All of them are integers, so it can only be $-2\times1$ or $2\times(-1)$.

List out all possibility the solutions can only be any permutation of $(1,1,1,-2)$ or $(-1,-1,-1,2)$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Subtract equation 2 from equation 1 and equ 3 from equ 1 to get
\begin{align*}
(a-d)(b-c)&=0\\
(a-c)(b-d)&=0
\end{align*}

From this we can infer that either $a=d$ or $b=c$ and either $a=c$ or $b=d$. Now try these possibilities in the system given. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Squaring the equations gives

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a^2b^2 +2abcd+ c^2d^2 = 1 \\
a^2c^2 +2abcd +b^2d^2 = 1 \\
a^2d^2 + 2abcd+b^2c^2 = 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Subtracting them yields

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
(a^2-b^2)(c^2-d^2)=0 \\
(a^2-c^2)(b^2-d^2)=0 \\
(a^2-d^2)(b^2-c^2)=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Now consider some cases.